# How to allocate variable size array in C90?

Tags: c, warnings, c89

I  need to allocate a varibale size for SYMBOLs,

`typedef int SYMBOL`

I did in following way

`SYMBOL test[nc]`, here  `nc`  is an integer. But this gives me following warning:

`ISO C90 forbids variable-size array`

How could i do it without getting warning?

Thanks,
Thetna

Comment: Why not use C99? You can do this with gcc by adding the -std=c99 option.

Comment: @Richard, why don't you turn this into an answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would have to allocate it using `malloc`:

```
SYMBOL* test = malloc(sizeof(SYMBOL) * nc);

// ...

free(test);
```

Variable length arrays are not allowed in C90, I think they were introduced in C99.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that variable-sized arrays reside on the stack and it's rather different than asking the operating system to allocate memory.

Answer (score 4):

The `alloca` library function was intended for that before variable-sized arrays were introduced.

It all has to do with incrementing the stack pointer. For the declaration of a typical constant-size array, the stack pointer is incremented with a constant that is known at compile-time. When a variable-size array is declared, the stack pointer is incremented with a value which is known at runtime.

Comment: But `alloca` was a non standard extension, and in general for objects of unknown size you should use `malloc`: the heap allows much bigger objects to be store, and in case of failure having a `NULL` returned is much better than getting a stack overflow.

Comment: @Matteo: of course the stack shouldn't be used to store big objects, but it's reasonable to use it for an object whose size is within some small limits rather than asking the operating system to do so.

Comment: sure thing, I was just pointing out that (1) you shouldn't use the stack for big stuff and (2) you may not find `alloca` in all the compilers. :)

Answer (score 3):

Use `malloc`. Here you can allocate an array with the size of the input:

```
int *p;
int n;
scanf(" %d", &n);
p = malloc( n * sizeof(int) );
```

Also, you can access the array using (`p[0]`, `p[1]`,...) notation.

Comment: `malloc` usually involves a system call and will be much slower than simply incrementing the stack pointer.

Comment: @Blagovest What you mean by incrementing the stack pointer? I'm not sure about what you said, but you can access an restrict memory block, right?

Comment: @Blagovest: actually in general `malloc` do not involve a system call, the C heap should be managed by the C runtime in user mode (at least when the allocation size do not exceed certain limits).

Answer (score 1):

Why not use C99? You can do this with gcc by adding the -std=c99 option. If the compiler is smart enough to recognize that a feature is C90 vs. something else, I bet it is smart enough to handle C99 features.

Comment: Actually, i tried with the option -std=c99 and it works too. But , i was looking for the some other way if i can do it in C90 too.